# array_rand password

Tags: php, arrays, random, passwords, auto-generate

```
<?php
$abc = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o','p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++)
    {   
        $pass = array_rand($abc);
        echo $abc[$pass];
    }

?>
```

I need to send email with generated pass but i must generated pass get to some variable but i dont now how.

Comment: @Dagon Could you please list those thousands? ;)

Comment: This is a very basic php thing... level 100 class... how to access a variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+random+password first 623, the rest are available on written request

Comment: lol, yeah, this is programming 101

Comment: Search engines are your friends.

Comment: People are still submitting answers...I guess that's the only way to raise your reputation around here: regurgitate the same info out over and over *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use this: `$newpass = substr(md5(uniqid()),0,8);`

It's not particularly secure, but it does the job and users are required to change their passwords as soon as they log in with a reset password. The point is it's more efficient than loops and character accesses.

Comment: +1. `base64_encode(md5(uniqid()))` can give a tough password.

Comment: @AyeshK But a long one. Do you really want your users to have to type in a 45-character long password just to get back on their account?

Comment: Sorry I meant to put your substr() there. 
`substr(base64_encode(md5(uniqid())),0,8);`

Comment: @AyeshK - What is the base64_encode for? An MD5 will already return an encoded value, so you gain nothing.

Comment: md5 returns only lowercase English letters and numbers. base64_encode will give you uppercase characters as well, making the password tough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mcrypt extention's iv function to get random data from the system. Because it is a bit-stream you need to encode it in some way, so that it is not garbage on the screen. Base64 encoding should suffice. Because base64 encoded strings are approximately 33% longer you need to cut the string down to the length you want.

Here is a simple example:

```
function password($length = 10) {
    $random = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $base64 = base64_encode($random);
    return substr($base64, 0, $length);
}
var_dump(password(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

User this snippet of code that I wrote a few days back.

```
function genText($length) {
    $out_str = '';
    $p_chars = "AGHACEFHJKRSTVXY124579aghacefhjkrstvxy"; // can be any set of characters
    while (strlen($out_str) < $length) {
        $out_str.= $p_chars{rand() % (strlen($p_chars))};
    }
    return $out_str;
}

$your_variable = genText(8);
```